# Does soci support Binary_Double data type?

Tags: soci

When executing query via SOCI Handler, following error occurred.

`db column type 32556 not supported for dynamic selects`

I want to know whether SOCI supports BINARY_DOUBLE data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your 2nd question:

> I want to know whether SOCI supports BINARY_DOUBLE data type.

As it appears, `BINARY_DOUBLE` support is implemented in SOCI: [Commit reference](https://github.com/SOCI/soci/commit/af80fd83899882d32f1d90e31d5c74e1a568626a). But to be released through [SOCI4](https://github.com/SOCI/soci/wiki/Roadmap)?